# Same navigation bar in every page using JS

Tags: javascript, html, express, require, navigationbar

I know there is multiple ways to include a **navigation bar** using **JS** or **JQuery** and the script tag in the page you will use it,but for me ,this is not ideal,cause once you use the script tag,you can no longer use JS in your page.Is there a way you can create a nav-bar using js,(f.e. **navbar.js**), then lets say for example i have a **frontpage.html** with **src="frontpage.js"** and in frontpage.js,i can use **require('./navbar.js')** that will create my navbar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("req/nav.html");
});
```

You can use this technique in Jquery. Just Simple.